# How to install OpenVPN with 2-factor authentication?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, authentication

I've installed OpenVPN over Ubuntu 16.4.2, and I'm trying to add 2-factor authentication using Google Authenticator.
Does someone've got a manual or some kind of user guide how to do that ?

Thanks,

Shimon.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a fully functional VPN server I continued the configuration using this manual :

https://www.howtoforge.com/securing-openvpn-with-a-one-time-password-otp-on-ubuntu

One important thing that is not mentioned in the manual: 
to every user that is going to use this VPN a user account with a specific folder must be created.
The Google-Authenticator store the credentials on the user home folder.